# How to open the "Find Font" window in InDesign with Applescript

Tags: window, applescript, adobe-indesign

As the title says, I have a script running that checks for missing fonts in an InDesign document. I want it to harass the person with the "Find Font" window until the issue is resolved or they click the "Ignore" button, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to trigger the "Find Font" window to come up.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with or without ellipses.

Comment: It's just (Type>Find Font...) No default shortcut and I can't trust people to make one. Used this to test with. > tell application "System Events"
 tell application id "com.adobe.InDesign" to activate
 tell application "System Events" to click menu item "Find Font..." of menu 1 of menu bar item "Type" of menu bar 1 of application process "Adobe InDesign CC 2017"
end tell

Comment: Ahh, I assumed script editor would auto format it. Either way, didn't work. Something odd though while trying to debug this. I stepped through getting the names of every menu item of each menu of menu bar 1. Once I get to InDesign I start getting "missing value." for some of the menu bar items. Example : {missing value, missing value, "Hide InDesign", "Hide Others", "Show All", missing value, "Quit InDesign", "Quit and Keep Windows"}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158645/discussion-between-user3439894-and-pixel).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay so, I found out the solution. It won't read the menu items UNLESS the menu is already open. I was able to do the following.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Adobe InDesign CC 2017"
        click menu "Type" of menu bar 1
        click menu item "Find Font..." of menu "Type" of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

menu actions is the way to go here...

```
tell application "Adobe InDesign CC 2015" to invoke item 1 of (menu actions whose name is "Find Font...")
```